# How to concatenate indefinite number of arrays of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, concatenation

I have an array of Groups s.t. each Group has many Users

I want to return all (unique) Users for a given array of Groups.

So far, I have

```
  let actor = await User.query().findById(req.user.id).eager('groups') // find the actor requesting


let actor_groups = actor.groups // find all groups of actor


  if (actor_groups.length > 1)
    var actor_groups_users = actor_groups[0].user
    for (let i = 0; i < actor_groups.length; i++) {
      const actor_groups_users = actor_groups_users.concat(actor_groups[i]);
    }
    console.log('actor groups users is', actor_groups_users);
  else 
    // return users from the first (only) group
```

which returns the error: `actor_groups_users is not defined`

Feels like a roundabout way to do this. Is there a way to just combine actor_groups into a single combined group?

Comment: Remove the `const` in front of this `const actor_groups_users = actor_groups_users.concat(actor_groups[i]);`.  You don't want to be defining a new variable, you want to be using the one you've already defined.

Comment: If you have an array of arrays, you can use the newer array method `.flat()` to combine them all.

Comment: how do you determine uniqueness of the users? by the identity of the objects or by their id?

Comment: ids. thanks. I think I can handle the uniqueness constraint.  Will try the flat method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
const allGroupsArrs = actor_groups.map(({ user }) => user);
const actor_groups_users = [].concat(...allGroupArrs);
```

Or, you could simply use the `.flat()` method, which is not yet officially part of the ES standard, but is on its way there and has browser support outside of IE:

```
const allGroupsArrs = actor_groups.map(({ user }) => user);
const actor_groups_users = allGroupArrs.flat();
```

Also, the above would result in duplicate values in `actor_groups_users` if there are people who are in multiple groups. You can remedy this (assuming the array elements are primitive values) using a `Set`:

```
const unique_users = [...new Set(actor_groups_users)];
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly the actor_group variable looks something like : 
`[{user: ['ok','boom']}, {user: 'er'}]` and he wants ['ok', 'boom', 'er']. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Also `[...actor_groups]` is equivalent to `[].concat(...actor_groups);`

Comment: @YounesM Not if `actor_groups` is an array of arrays. `[...actor_groups]` just makes a shallow copy of `actor_groups` whereas `[].concat(...actor_groups)` flattens it.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can cycle through, adding users if not already in the array, using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

*This is assuming that `group.user` is an **Array** of users.*

```
let users = [];

// check that actor_groups has items in it
if (actor_groups && actor_groups.length > 1) {

   // cycle through each actor_group
   actor_groups.forEach( group => {

      // check if we have a 'user' array with items in it
      if (group.user && group.user.length > 1) {

         // cycle through each user in the group
         group.user.forEach( user => {

            // check if we already have this user
            // if not, add it to users
            if (!users.includes(user)) {
               users.push(user);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I can think of is

```
const users = [...new Set([...actor_groups].flatMap(el => el.user))]
```

I used this example:

```
const actor_groups = [{user: ['ok','boom']}, {user: 'er'}]
console.log([...new Set([...actor_groups].flatMap(el => el.user))])
//output: ["ok", "boom", "er"]
```